# SASS Variables are written to CSS file with VS 2013 Web Essentials

Tags: css, visual-studio-2013, sass, web-essentials

I use Visual Studio 2013 Express for Web Update 2 with Web Essentials Update 2 to write a SASS (SCSS Synthax) file. The compiled CSS file contains the variable names instead of the values. The following code

```css
$height: 200px;
#contentDiv {
  height: calc(100% - $height);
}
```

produces this CSS

```css
#contentDiv {
  height: calc(100% - $height); }
```

So what am I doing wrong? I created a simple Web Project, installed Web Essentials, added a SASS file and started writing the code (new to SASS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't subtract pixels from a percentage using Sass's `calculate` function because they aren't compatible types.

If you want to use CSS's calculate function then you can do this:

```
$something: 100px;

#contentDiv {
  height: calc(100% - #{$something});
}
```

Which compiles to:

```
#contentDiv {
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

Comment: but this is from w3.org: `width: calc(100%/3 - 2*1em - 2*1px);` so I thought 'everything' is possible? And this from developers.mozilla.org docs: `width: calc(100% - 80px);`

Comment: Thank you this one works now. But I am not sure why I had to add `#{}`. This was not apparent from the Sass Tutorial.

Comment: Basically it forces Sass to treat the contents as SassScript as opposed to CSS because that's what it was expecting (within a `calc()`) . See interpolation in the reference doc for more info http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_

Answer (score 1):

I use http://sassmeister.com to check your compilation.

Aparently the error is over the function **calc**

```
$something: 100px;

#contentDiv {
  heigth: calc(100% - $something); //doesn't work
  heigth: calculate(100% - $something); //work with errors
  height: $something;//work
}
```